# Where do we store username/password/endpoint...in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

We have a web application developed in Salesforce (apex classes/ triggers and visualforce pages). This web application is talking to our APIs externally using endpoint urls with username and password. As of right now these password/username and endpoint url are being stored in apex classes as constant strings.

In an ASP.Net application or we would usually store the credential/endpoint url in a web.config file. But in Salesforce where do we store these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either a protected Custom Setting in managed package (you would have to create this similar to creating an object, I would use the List type and try to make it as generic as possible to support many use cases) or Named Credentials, or possibly a Custom Metadata type, definitely not in code

Comment: If it is a custom metadata, and you deploy as a package to a different org, will the passwords go through?, will be correct to assume, protected custom setting for this kind of scenario?

Comment: What type of package managed package, unlocked package or just a first gen packages? In general yes they will be available, but you need to include the records also.  In terms of access to the records via code, the rules are similar to custom settings, in that it must be in a managed package otherwise they (protected types) behave the same as public types so they would be accessible by all profiles.  IMO if you are not using managed code, Named Credentials is the way to go , otherwise just use a custom object with encrypted fields, at least you can hide the object and fields from profiles ...

Comment: ... But you must be aware the Apex runs in system mode by default, so anyone with the write apex permission  can run code to read the values.

Comment: It is a manage packaged, how would you manage named credential, if you want each org that the package will be install if they have different user names, and if this userrnames change time to time, I guess in this scenario named credentials is not a good fit?, want i didnt realized with custom metadata, was that i can picked the records, i thought it was like named credentials and the record will be "stuck" with the package